# Set non responsive page width to device width, cross-browser

Tags: javascript, html, css

First of all, I know that what I'm trying to do here is bad practice, but I dont really have much choice, so please don't answer with "make the page responsive" etc..

I have a website (its a facebook app) that I should make compatible with mobile devices.
The entire design is based on a fixed width (810px for the Facebook app, which I reduced to 520px for the mobile page). Reducing the width was all I could do, making the page responsive would require me to rewrite the entire html and css and some javascript and we agreed that simply fitting the page would be enough.

Now I want this 520px page to always fit the viewport width (in portrait and landscape) in a way that should work cross-browser and cross-os on smartphones.

I tried with the viewport meta tag:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=true;">
```

but that won't work in almost any browser, since every browser seems to have different behaviour for this. I found solutions for single browsers that work (more or less) but on some browsers this simply doesn't seem possible.

**Is there any way to achieve this using CSS and/or JavaScript?**

Here is the HTML code I use for testing. It's simply a 520x2000px box with a gradient as background.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=true;"> 
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <style type="text/css">
            body,html {
                margin:0;
                padding:0;
            }

            /* white->blue->black gradient */
            .gradient {
                background: -moz-linear-gradient(left,  #ffffff 0%, #0078b5 50%, #000000 100%); /* FF3.6+ */
                background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, right top, color-stop(0%,#ffffff), color-stop(50%,#0078b5), color-stop(100%,#000000)); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
                background: -webkit-linear-gradient(left,  #ffffff 0%,#0078b5 50%,#000000 100%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
                background: -o-linear-gradient(left,  #ffffff 0%,#0078b5 50%,#000000 100%); /* Opera 11.10+ */
                background: -ms-linear-gradient(left,  #ffffff 0%,#0078b5 50%,#000000 100%); /* IE10+ */
                background: linear-gradient(to right,  #ffffff 0%,#0078b5 50%,#000000 100%); /* W3C */
            }               
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="gradient" style="border:3px solid orange;width:520px;height:2000px;">

        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Have you tried changing the meta tag to something like this? `<meta name="viewport" content="width=520, user-scalable=0">`

Comment: I just tried that and it does work in Firefox, Chrome and Opera on android, but not on browsers that use the standard webkit (like Dolphin or the default browser, they only zoom in, but they dont zoom out and that would be needed here). but it might just be acceptable if it works on iOS Safari (which i sadly can't check because I don't have an iPhone available right now).

Comment: @PedroEstrada i just tried it again with `width=520, user-scalable=1` and that works in all browsers on android and i guess it will work with safari too. if your write that as an answer i will accept it. (for my example it would be `width=526` because of the 3px borders)

Comment: Sure thing! I'll write it right now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per OP's request.

Modify your meta tag to this

`<meta name="viewport" content="width=526, user-scalable=1">`